# Apigee : Javascript callout policy return error response. How can I resolve this error?

Tags: javascript, apigee

this is my js code in js callout policy

```
var payload = JSON.parse(request.content);
var headers = {'Content-Type' : 'application/json'};
var url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
var operation = "POST";
var req = new Request(url, operation, headers, payload);
var calloutResponse1 = httpClient.send(req);
context.session['calloutResponse1'] = calloutResponse1;
```

I use this curl for call proxy

```
curl -k https://xxxxxx/poc3 -d '{"name": "Apple MacBook Pro 16", "data": "s"}'
```

this is response error from js callout policy

> {"fault":{"faultstring":"Execution of callapi1 failed on line callapi1_js#5 with error: Unexpected Type. Expected "String" got "NativeObject"","detail":{"errorcode":"steps.javascript.ScriptExecutionFailedLineNumber"}}}

What is problem?
How can I resolve this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing payload as a JSON object to `Request()`. It should be of type `String`.

```js
var payload = request.content; // Do not parse the JSON
```